# How to get current line number in Qt Script code?

Tags: qt, qtscript

Is there a way to obtain current line number in executing Qt Script, using objects and functions in it?

Answer (score 0):

```
var lineNumber = 1;
try {
    unexsistedVariable1 + unexsistedVariable2; //we have got number of this line
}
catch(e) {
    lineNumber = e.lineNumber;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `__LINE__` int constant, which will be filled when you compile the code.